# How to move slot and slot-scope to vue 3 v-slot rule

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, ant-design-vue

I get this error when I'm using Ant-design **table** for VueJS

```html
<template slot="name" slot-scope="name"> {{ name.first }} {{ name.last }} </template>
```

After I changed to Vue 3 rules still nothing showed:

```html
<template v-slot:name v-slot="name"> {{ name.first }} {{ name.last }} </template>
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your markup below doesn't work because it marks the template with two slot names; i.e., the `name` slot (in `v-slot:name`) as well as the `default` slot (in `v-slot="name"`):

```html
<template v-slot:name v-slot="name"> {{ name.first }} {{ name.last }} </template>
          ^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here's the correct fix:

```html
<template v-slot:name="name"> {{ name.first }} {{ name.last }} </template>
```

Answer (score 3):

Base on this link https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#scoped-slots
we can use like this :

**Old Version :**

```
<template slot="header" slot-scope="headerProps">
    {{ headerProps }}
  </template>
```

**New update :**

```
<MyComponent>
  <template #header="headerProps">
    {{ headerProps }}
  </template>

  <template #default="defaultProps">
    {{ defaultProps }}
  </template>

  <template #footer="footerProps">
    {{ footerProps }}
  </template>
</MyComponent>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [documentation](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-deprecated-slot-attribute.html) you should change `slot` to `v-slot`

Comment: Yes, I've tried but I get an error instead `<template v-slot="from">
      {{ from.host }}
      {{ from.addrs }}
    </template>`

Comment: What error are you getting? You can try changing `v-slot="from"` to `v-slot:from` as mentioned in the [documentation](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-deprecated-slot-attribute.html)

Comment: Actually nothing showed when I changed to `v-slot="from"` or `v-slot:from` in the <template> tag